# Maintaining state across asynchronous events in javascript

Tags: javascript, events, asynchronous, callback, rxjs

We have a loader which is based on an event listener. This is through pouchdb.

So each time a document is received to the client the listener fires. We check if that document is related to the loader and then after another async callback update the percentage in a UI global variable.

Now the problem is

1. A response is received from the server and The listener is added to the event queue
2. Another response is received from the server and The listener is added to the event queue
3. The eventListener method is called for the first event queue element
4. The doAsyncCallbackithVerification is added to the event queue
5. The eventListener method is called for the second event queue element
6. The doAsyncCallbackithVerification is added to the event queue
7. The doAsyncCallbackithVerification method is called and the percentage is updated to 85
8. The doAsyncCallbackithVerification method is called and the percentage is updated to 85 again

When we would expect the percentage to be 90 (since number of method call times is 2 and 2 * 5)

---

```
var percentage = 80;
function eventListener() {
  if(loaderRelated){
    doAsyncCallbackithVerification(percentage, function(newPercentage){
      percentage = newPercentage;
    });
  }
}

db.listenForTheEvents(eventListener);
```

What is the normal standard to handle this, keeping in mind what I wrote above was javascript pseudocode based on a much more complex case then. We also use RxJs so could that be used to mitigate these scenarios and if so how.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you *want* to happen. Should the second callback change the percentage to a different number?

Comment: Yes that would be the expected output, I also edited the pseudocode slightly to pass in the state value. The given expected output will be 90 then.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only provdided pseudo-code, it is hard to give a precise answer, but this is about how I would do it with RxJS:

```
const listenToDb = Observable.fromCallback(db.listenForTheEvents);  // in RxJS5 it's 'bindCallback'
const asyncCbWithVerif = Observable.fromCallback(db.doAsyncCallbackWithVerification);  // in RxJS5 it's 'bindCallback'

const fetchPercentage$ = listenToDb()
    .filter(event => isLoaderRelated(event))      // don't propagate any unrelated events
    .switchMap(event => asyncCbWithVerif(event))  // if some new event arrives, the switchMap will automatically cancel the last call of 'asyncCbWithVerif'
    .do(newPercentage => console.log(newPercentage));

fetchPercentage$.subscribe(); // or however you wish to activate the stream, maybe publish & share, maybe replay, ect...
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply pass the event handler a percentage to add to the completed total. In pseudocode to match your question:

```
var percentage = 80;
function eventListener() {
  if(loaderRelated){
    doAsyncCallbackithVerification(percentage, function(percentageCompleted){
      percentage += percentageCompleted;
    });
  }
}

db.listenForTheEvents(eventListener);
```